# Conditional color of display only item - Oracle Apex 20.2

Tags: dynamic, colors, formatting, oracle-apex

I'm new to Oracle APEX, using v.20.2

**Scenario:**
I load a "Form" region via PL/SQL dynamically created SQL code depending on an instrument grid selections primary key and some dropdowns (going to different schematas).

**What I want:**
Most of the "Items" in the "Form" are type "Display Only". Some of the values returned by the SQL are NULL. For two of them, I want to set the text for NULL values to 'N/A' and color them red. I want to avoid using javascript and build it with APEX internal possibilities as far as possible.

**What I have already achived:**
I created dynamic events for Event "Change" for each of the two fields with client-side condition Item is null. For Result True I created action "Set Value" to static assignment *N/A*. This works well.

**What doesn't work:**
I created an additional action "Set Style" with Settings "Style Name" = *color* and "Value" = *red*.
This doesn't work. However when changing the field types of the affected fields to "Text Field" it works just fine (but then I (of course) get a warning about changed values when I try to leave the site - which would be actually desired for non-N/A cases).

Is this a bug, not possible at all for display only fields or does my approach have an error?

Thanks a lot in advance for some hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, that region is based on your PL/SQL procedure.

So, why wouldn't you do the job right there, in PL/SQL procedure? For example, this will display `N/A` instead of `NULL`:

```
select case when name is null then 'N/A'
            else name
       end as name
from ...
```

If you want to include colors, then

```
select case when name is null then 
                 '<span style="color:red">'  || 'N/A' || '</span>'
            else '<span style="color:blue">' || name  || '</span>'
       end as name
from ...
```

Doing so, you'd avoid dynamic actions. See if it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes, this works. I would have hoped to avoid this and being able to work *with* apex instead of *around* apex, since it works just fine with built in "masterdata" features for text boxes. But yes, end result is what I wanted. ♥

(however as an addition: this doesn't work for date fields because I'd need a to_char for type conversion to string. It will display the <span...> stuff as content of the field then.

e.g.
 ' case when ie_erst.e_datum is null then ''<span style="color:red">N/A</span>'' else to_char(ie_erst.e_datum, ''DD-MON-YYYY'') END as install_date, '

Comment: Regarding my previous comment on dates: it works with dates when the option Security --> Escape special characters is turned off in the items settings!

Comment: Exactly, escaping special characters is a *must*. I forgot to say that, but I'm glad you found it yourself.